# Ffmpeg chain references to other parts of the command for dynamic watermark size

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, encoding

I have been reading the ffmpeg documents for a while now. But I can't seem to wrap my mind around how the filters, naming and backreferences work. Or whether what I want is even possible.

I am trying to convert a watermark into a output source. This onto itself is not undocumented, but what I cant find is how to use dimensions from one part in the calculations of another.

For example, encoding a fixed watermark onto a video:

```
ffmpeg -y -threads 8 -i bunny-source.mp4 \
-i wm.png -filter_complex \
"[1:v]scale=100:-1[watermark]; [0:v][watermark]overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10[outv]" \
-map "[outv]" -map 0:a  marked.mp4
```

This generates a watermark of 100px in the bottom of the output. I understand that the output of a complex filter is named in the finishing [brackets]. I found out that the first parameter in the [a:b] is the numeric index of the input (-i). But what does the :v mean. And how would I go about changing the command so that instead of 100, i get 30% of the input source width? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

> But what does the `:v` mean?

This is the [stream specifier](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1). For example, `1:v` refers to `second input:all video streams` (note that `ffmpeg` starts counting from 0).

This can be refined even more; `1:v:2` refers to `second input:video stream type:third video stream`. So this will choose the third video stream from the second input.

> How would I go about changing the command so that instead of 100 pixel width, I get 30% of the input source width?

In the scale filter the values of the `w` and `h` options are expressions that, among other things, can reference the input width (`iw`) and height (`ih`). So your command would look like:

```
ffmpeg -y -i bunny-source.mp4 -i wm.png -filter_complex \
"[1:v]scale=iw*0.3:-1[watermark]; \
 [0:v][watermark]overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10[outv]" \
-map "[outv]" -map 0:a  marked.mp4
```

This will scale `wm.png` to 30% of its width, and therefore also height since you used `-1` which will automatically choose the correct value based on the given value while preserving the aspect ratio.

See the [FFmpeg scale video filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) for more info.

Comment: Hi Lord, Thanks for your reply, But i tinkered around with the different token values. But all references to input widths seem to reference the input width of the watermark, not the input width of the first video stream. So iw*0.3 => 30% of the png image.